# Adding DebuggerStepThrough attribute to class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging

I want to add [DebuggerStepThrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx) attribute to all methods of my class. Is it enough to add `DebuggerStepThrough` to the class?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes adding it to the class will cause the whole class (methods, properties, etc) to be bypassed by the debugger.